# Tomcat memory consumption issue

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks

I have a java application running on tomcat with xmx=2GB
I see memory consumption slowly raises on tomcat, exceeding the 2GB heap limit.
Going through this forum I know that there more than just the heap consuming the memory.

The problem is that memory keeps raising above 3 and even 4GB until no more memory is available on the machine, and I need to restart tomcat.

Looking at the GC log, I see that the heap does not exceed 2GB.

My question is how can I find and analyze the memory been used.
Also, can it be code related?
It is obviously some kind of leak, but I don't know how to locate and fix it, or even identify the source (my code, tomcat, etc).

Thanks
Maayan

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate, who says the code is the problem?  What is accessing your web application, and how frequent are the requests?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is more likely to be a memory leak in your code than in tomcat, I'd start here.

Create a heap dump using [JMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html), and try to analyze it using a tool like the [Eclipe Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
As I mentioned, when Iooking at the heap dump GC log, I see that the heap do not exceed 2GB, so how can it be a code leak?